# Geoserver REST example not working

Tags: geoserver, development, rest

I am trying to follow the example to create a new REST service in Geoserver:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/rest-services/implementing.html

After building, accessing the service at `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/hello.txt` doesn't do anything.

(REST is working since `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest`  will show me the Geoserver Configuration API)

I have also tried within eclipse.  To me it seems that I need to add some configuration somewhere to get the rest services to know about my new "hello world" rest service and add it to the geoserver rest services?

Can someone explain how to get this example to work?

Thanks

Comment: What Operating System are you building the REST Service on?

Comment: Using windows 7